# Can I Open HDF4 or 5 File in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, hdf

First. I checked Export Function that NetCDF File to Hdf File, but Read Hdf4 and Present is not available.

How can i read HDF4 or HDF5 File in GeoServer? Is any plugins or Library for Read HDF Files?

Please recommend any plugin or solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, and based on [this discussion](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/HDF-Files-in-GeoServer-td3824253.html) on the mailing list I doubt it will be supported any time soon.